# Is the robot seen in the Wayne Security commercial a known DC entity?

Tags: dc, character-identification, powerless-tv

Here is the robot in question.

[image]

**Some half forgotten robot from a bygone DC era comic, or something new?**

Comment: Looks a little like a giant Bozo the Iron Man, but hard to be sure.

Comment: Robotman from the Doom Patrol?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it could be the robot villain from Metal Men #15.[image]